# Mule Persistent storage

Tags: queue, mule, persistent

I am trying to use persistent queue storage to recover from unexpected failure. My mule version is 3.3.1

I pick up messages from a queue and enter "until successful" loop. If mule stops for some reason, I would like the message to be persistent.

Here is my relevant code

```
<spring:bean id="outboundStore" class="org.mule.util.store.QueuePersistenceObjectStore" />

<until-successful objectStore-ref="outboundStore"
```

I do not see the messages in .mule directory. What am I doing wrong?

Sorry if the question is not clear.

Adding Flows as requested:

```
<flow name="InitialFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="firstQueue"/>
    <until-successful objectStore-ref="outboundStore" maxRetries="6" secondsBetweenRetries="5" deadLetterQueue-ref="secondQueue" failureExpression="groovy:message.getInvocationProperty('soapResponse') == 'BAD'">
        <flow-ref name="somSubFlow" />
    </until-successful>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="someSubFlow">
<http:outbound-endpoint ref="someEndpoint" exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" />  
</sub-flow>
```

Please do let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please provide the flow config completely. It might help in addressing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a configuration very similar to yours, I can totally see messages pending delivery written in the `.mule/queuestore/queuestore` directory.

The only thing I can think of is an issue with this expression `groovy:message.getInvocationProperty('soapResponse') == 'BAD'` that would somehow mess with the processing.

Is this expression correct? Why not using MEL?

Comment: The groovy expression works fine for retries, although, I could change it to MEL. Will need sometime to figure out the MEL :) Sorry...newbie. Thanks for your response. I'll post my findings tomorrow morning.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any specific setting to be done on the vm:endpoint? Sorry, I don't have my code with me, else would have provided. I think my code is something like <vm:endpoint name="firstQueue" path="someFirstQueue"/>

Comment: I removed the failure expression and yet no luck. I would like to mention that I'm starting the Mule Server from within STS. Would that have something do do with it?

Comment: I deployed the application on a local mule server and it is working fine! Apparently, it doesn't work when I start the mule server from within STS. Someone with more knowledge can throw some light:)

Comment: No, I'm starting from within plain Eclipse - not Mule Studio - and I have file system storage of the `until-sucessful` working fine. I would specify the exchange pattern on the VM endpoint, for the sake of clarity. Have you thought more about what could be a good failure expression for your case? Maybe checking the status code of the HTTP call instead of checking a random flow variable named `soapResponse`.

Comment: I tried HTTP header, but my requirement is to retry only on Service Unavailble. If I call service "A" which in turn calls service "B" (SOAP calls), even if Service B is unavailable, I need to retry. I couldn't find a better way:(. My vm endpoint has an exchange pattern of one-way.
 <vm:connector name="vmConnector" numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="20">
     <vm:queue-profile maxOutstandingMessages="500000" >
         <file-queue-store/>
     </vm:queue-profile>
 </vm:connector>
<vm:endpoint name="firstQueue" path="someFirstQueue" exchange-pattern="one-way" connector-ref="vmConnector" />